# Cannot download a file

Tags: html

```
<a href="file:///C:\Users\test\git\irs\IRS-Web\src\main\webapp\uploads\test\2017-08-02 10_03_37-IRLS.png" download="2017-08-02 10_03_37-IRLS.png" >prev</a>
```

Trying to download an image file from my C drive, but it's not downloading. It shows network error.
If I try this path directly on browser, it loads the image:

> file:///C:\Users\test\git\irs\IRS-Web\src\main\webapp\uploads\test\2017-08-02
>   10_03_37-IRLS.png

How can I download a file using chrome browser?

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and follow the guildlines, then you'll know what you're doing wrong

Comment: are you working with your local server ?

Comment: are you working with your local server ?if you are using that better your keep your files in the project folder by creating a directory,Then you share the download link try it